# Using target _blank on site is forcing mobile redirect even on desktop

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, redirect, mobile

I have two sites, one for mobile and one for desktop. Both sites are django apps built using angular. The desktop site seems to have a bug where any links generated should be passing the mobile redirect and continuing on to the desktop, however, they are not passing this and only when using `target="_blank"` on a link does it redirect.

In `controllers.js`, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //showA();
  mobileRedirect();
  if($route.current.params.aId){
    a.set($route.current.params.aId,$route.current.params.bId);
  };
  tryCookieLogin();
});
```

now mobile redirect is based off of:

```
function mobileRedirect() {
    var viewport = getWindowSize();
     console.log('viewport: '+viewport.width)
    if (viewport.width<650){
      //console.log('switch to mobile')
      if(isA()){
        var urlA = 'http://example.com/mobile/#/a/'+$route.current.params.aId+'/b/'+$route.current.params.bId;
      }else{
        var urlA = 'http://example.com/mobile/';
      }
      window.location.href = urlA;
    }
}
```

and getWindowSize:

```
function getWindowSize() {
    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;

        $scope.windowWidth

    return { width: x, height: y };
}
```

So why is it that if I make a link that uses `target="_blank"`, regardless of screen size, that it redirects to mobile? Whereas a link not using `target` works fine?

Comment: Hi @redband. Never heard back regarding your question. If my answer helped, please upvote and award the answer. thx!

Answer (score 0):

the getWindowSize() function is returning the width and height of the window (not the width of the device screen).

So, if a new window is created using target="_blank" on your desktop and it is less than 650px wide, it would be subject to the mobile redirect).